# numpy/pandas: how to add a new column with values based on a list of indices?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For example, I have a long list of indices: {1,3,7,9,...}.

My numpy / pandas looks something like this:

```
Col1   Col2   
1       99
2       95
3       91
4       97
...
n       86
```

I would like to append an additional column taking values 0 or 1 depending on whether the leftmost column value can be found in the list of indices (1 if yes).

How do I do that, without looping over the list of indices? I've tried different approaches without success.

Much appreciated!

P.S. I do know that numpy goes by an array of arrays so each column would just correspond to an index in the numpy inner array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `col1` and `col2` are in a Pandas `DataFrame` called `df`...

```
selected_indices = [1,3,7,9]   

# set index as col1, since that seems to be the point of column1
df.set_index('col1')

# define col3 value as 0 or 1 based on selected_indices list
df['col3'] = 0
df['col3'].loc[selected_indices] = 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work if the index is not the same as col1.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and helpful response!

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**

```
l=[1,3,7,9]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 'Col2': {0: 99, 1: 95, 2: 91, 3: 97}})
df
Out[190]: 
   Col1  Col2
0     1    99
1     2    95
2     3    91
3     4    97
```

**Solution**

You can use np.in1d to check if Col1 exists in the indice list and then convert the bool results to int.

```
df['indicator'] = np.in1d(df.Col1,l).astype(int)

df
Out[186]: 
   Col1  Col2  indicator
0     1    99          1
1     2    95          0
2     3    91          1
3     4    97          0
```

Comment: not a criticism just a comment... this works in this case for filling values of `0` and `1`, but wouldn't work for conditionally filling other values like `apples` and `oranges` or `0` and `2`

Comment: @MaxPower, that's right. I guess in that case, we can use the result as a bool index to set desired values.